# I want to stop video player before navigation

Tags: flutter, navigation

This is my code, when I press on image button I call navigation but before that I want to stop the video.
I use you tube video player.

```
 Column(children: [
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: videoID.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                child: YoutubePlayer(
                  actionsPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
                  bottomActions: [
                    CurrentPosition(),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    ProgressBar(isExpanded: true),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
```

Here is navigation, I want to stop video player first before navigation on next page.
I try with youtube player controller method pause(). But I got error method was call on null.

```
                 GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => new CameraScreen(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage('asset/reenact.png'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  controller: YoutubePlayerController(
                    initialVideoId:
                        YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(videoID[index]),
                    flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
                      autoPlay: false,
                    ),
                  ),
                  progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blue,
                  progressColors: ProgressBarColors(
                    playedColor: Colors.blue,
                    handleColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your controller inside an `initState` not in your widget tree. Then you should be able to stop the video by using this controller.

```dart
YoutubePlayerController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId:YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(videoID[index]),
    flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(autoPlay: false),
  );
}

// ...

GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // Now you should be able to call pause() in before your navigation.
    _controller.pause();

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new CameraScreen()),
    );
  },
  child: Image(image: AssetImage('asset/reenact.png')),
),

// ...
```

Comment: I try it, now get error undefinded name index. My videoID is final List of Strings.

Comment: Probably because your index is not defined yet. Your index variable comes from your ListView.builder.

Comment: Yes, I  don't know how to define an index to make this work.

Comment: You could wrap your whole GestureDetector containing your YoutubePlayer widget into a StatefulWidget wich will be the one to have the YoutubePlayerController inside it. You would just have to pass the videoID[index] as a parameter of the widget.

Comment: Still not working, now in debug console I get The controller is not ready for method calls.